# Does Hadoop 3 support Mahout?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, hadoop3

I was wondering if any Mahout version has been confirmed to work properly with any version of Hadoop 3.x.
It looks like both Cloudera's and Amazon's Hadoop distribution removed Mahout when they went from Hadoop 2 to Hadoop 3. But I cannot find any reason for omitting Mahout.

Does anyone have a source or personal experience that indicates that Mahout can work with Hadoop 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hadoop version recommended by trunk branch of Mahout on git hub is hadoop-2.4.1

but take a look at this dockerfile on maser branch:
https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/docker/build/Dockerfile

it uses spark v2.3.1 on hadoop 3.0
*gettyimages/spark:2.3.1-hadoop-3.0*

hope it could help

Comment: I will add to this that I successfully ran a Mahout example script on a Hadoop cluster. I ran the Reuters clustering example from Mahout 0.13 on Hadoop 3.2.1.